# Regex Expression to split by "(letter or number)"

Tags: java, regex

Sorry, this question might have an answer already, but I can't seem to find it. I'm trying to split the following string:

```
Heading:
(A) point A
   (1) subpoint 1
   (2) subpoint 2
(B) point B
```

into:

```
[Heading:, point A, subpoint 1, subpoint 2, ... ]
```

My current code is this:

```
section.split("\n[\\(\\D\\)]");
```

Any help would be appreciated!
(Also, side question, would it be possible to keep the bullet in the split array? So that the array would have "(A) point A" instead of just "point A"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex of `\n\s*\(.\)\s?` returns

```
['Heading:', 'point A', 'subpoint 1', 'subpoint 2', 'point B']
```

and `\n\s*` returns

```
['Heading:', '(A) point A', '(1) subpoint 1', '(2) subpoint 2', '(B) point B']
```

Comment: This works, but once I get to (10) and so on it doesn't anymore. Any suggestions?

Comment: @sabraship Note that `.` will match any character (except line breaks), not just letters and numbers.

Comment: @sabraship You could make it `.+` instead of `.` to do multiple characters, although it'd definitely be better to restrict it to certain letters like Ahmed mentioned, `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` should work well.

Comment: It does not delete carriage return codes in Windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following pattern:

```
\s*\([0-9a-zA-Z]\)\s*
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/I0nU8W/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

```python
\s*         # Zero or more whitespace characters (including line breaks).
\(          # Matches '(' literally.
[0-9a-zA-Z] # Matches an English letter or digit.
\)          # Matches ')' literally.
\s*         # Zeror or more whitespace characters.
```

Note: If you want to match more than one letter or number, you may add a `+` after the character class (i.e., `[0-9a-zA-Z]+`).

**Java example:**

```
String pattern = "\\s*\\([0-9a-zA-Z]\\)\\s*";
String section = "Heading:\n"
     + "(A) point A\n"
     + "   (1) subpoint 1\n"
     + "   (2) subpoint 2\n"
     + "(B) point B";

String[] parts = section.split(pattern);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

**Output:**

```
[Heading:, point A, subpoint 1, subpoint 2, point B]
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/CDWV14155)**.